# How can I add in a batch multiple users to roles with SQL Server LocalDb

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code:

```
    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("r12345678", "abcdefgh", false);
    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("m12345678", "abcdefgh", false);
    System.Web.Security.Roles.CreateRole("Author");
    System.Web.Security.Roles.CreateRole("Admin");
    System.Web.Security.Roles.CreateRole("Super");
    System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUserToRole("r12345678", "Author");
    System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUserToRole("r12345678", "Admin");
    System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUserToRole("r12345678", "Super");
    System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUserToRole("m12345678", "Author");
    System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUserToRole("m12345678", "Admin");
```

The first 5 lines work good but then when it comes to this line:

```
    System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUserToRole("r12345678", "Super");
```

I get the following:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "webpages_Roles_UserProfiles_Target". The conflict occurred in database "T12345", table "dbo.UserProfile", column 'UserId'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I cannot understand why this is. I have a 100% fresh database. In fact I delete the database and recreate. Here's my SQL Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles] (
    [RoleId] INT NOT NULL,
    [UserId] INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RoleId] ASC, [UserId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [webpages_Roles_UserProfiles_Source] FOREIGN KEY ([RoleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[webpages_Roles] ([RoleId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [webpages_Roles_UserProfiles_Target] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserProfile] ([UserId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

My UserProfile table Contains:

```
UserId  UserName
1   r12345678
2   m12345678
```

My UsersInRoles table Contains:

```
RoleId  UserId
1       1
1       2
```

My Role table contains:

```
1   Author
2   Admin
3   Super
```

Does anyone have an idea why the Foreign Key constraint is getting triggered

Update:

Note that I tried the following and this did not work either. It gave a similar error:

```
Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] {"r12345678"}, new[] {"Author","Admin","Super"});
Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] {"m12345678" }, new[] { "Author", "Admin", "Super" });
```

Comment: The message suggests you are adding row for a UserId which is not in the UserProfile table.

Comment: Yes but there are only two userids and these are in that table. UserId 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue as well and it seems to be that the addUserToRole is inserting the userID into the roleID column and the Role ID into the UserID column which means that it can not find the userId that equals three and thus gives the error message.